# Dates comparison in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets. I want to pick the maximum value from the date range (AK) in the first sheet and then compare to the given date in the second sheet to print NEw and OLD. But my formula is not working and i am new to VBA.

My Formula

```
Set Rng = OldSheet.Range("AK2:AK" & OldLastRow)

'Worksheet function Max returns the Max value in a range
dblmax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)

With NewSheet

'Determine last row in col BG
NewLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

.Range("BL2:BL" & NewLastRow).Formula = "=IF(AK2>dblmax,""NEW"",""OLD"")"
```

After using the code, `dblmax` gets printed as `dblmax` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `dblmax` is a *VBA variable*, evaluate it in VBA and concatenate in the formula you pass to Excel:

```
.Range("BL2:BL" & NewLastRow).Formula = "=IF(AK2>" & dblmax & ",""NEW"",""OLD"")"
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```